# how to send a transaction using sdk uniswap.org

Tags: javascript, uniswap

i am trying to create and send a transaction to https://app.uniswap.org using SDK https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/

uniswap has two functions (swapExactTokensForETH and swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens) - tokens with and without fees. how to define a coin with or without commission? Otherwise, if sent incorrectly, the transaction will fail.

Answer (score 4):

I had to read how the pancakeswap frontend does this.

Basically, you calculate gas for BOTH methods. And the one that does not return an error, is the one you use.

e.g:

```
contract.methods.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
  Web3.utils.toHex(amountIn), Web3.utils.toHex(0), path, to, deadline
).estimateGas({
  from: activeAccount.address,
  gas: 5000000,
  value: web3.utils.toHex(0)
}, (error, result) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log('swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens: ', result);
});

contract.methods.swapExactTokensForETH(
  Web3.utils.toHex(amountIn), Web3.utils.toHex(0), path, to, deadline
).estimateGas({
  from: activeAccount.address,
  gas: 5000000,
}, (error, result) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log('swapExactTokensForETH: ', result);
});
```